# Bootstrap carousel Next button gets stuck going from 3rd to 4th slide

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have made a Carousel with Bootstrap with 5 images but when I click the Next button to go through the slides its fine until on the third click it freezes and never makes it to the fourth slide, i'd be grateful for any solution so the Next button works for all slides, heres my code-

```
       <div class="container">

        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        </ol>


        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
            <img src="images2/MindBodyPilatesLogo1Carousel.png" alt="logo">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images2/Voucher3Carousel.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images2/EagleCarousel.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="item">
      <img src="images2/RestCarousel.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="item">
      <img src="images2/AndyPosterCarousel.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/tracelarge.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div> 

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to make a jsfiddle.

Comment: Have you validated your HTML? Have you checked your HTML with [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint)

Comment: Thank you for your support here and I found I had saved my 4th image allot larger then the Carousel viewer size so it was getting stuck